# Upgrade from craft 2 fails due to read-only mode

Tags: error, craft2, updates, upgrades, project.yaml

I'm trying to upgrade an old Site from Craft 2.9.x. The goal is to eventually upgrade to Craft 4.x, but I thought it would be easier to first update to Craft 3.x. When trying to `Finish up` my database, I always get the following error:

```
Not Supported: Changes to the project config are not possible while in read-only mode.
Migration: craft\migrations\m180521_173000_initial_yml_and_snapshot
```

I tried upgrading to Craft 3.2.x and 3.7.x with the same result. I have never heard of any read-only mode in Craft. I found this thread which seems to have a similar issue, but I don't find any working solution in this thread. I know that the error comes from the first time all the YAML files get created (from Craft 3.1.x), but I don't get how I could fix this error. Any inputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The goal is to eventually upgrade to Craft 4.x, but I thought it would be easier to first update to Craft 3.x

Not just easier; upgrading to the latest 3.x release is a prerequisite for upgrading to Craft 4. But FWIW, it should be completely possible to migrate straight from 2.9.2 to the latest 3.7.x release; I did it just the other day.

> Not Supported: Changes to the project config are not possible while in read-only mode.

That error message will appear if something (a migration, in this case) is trying to change something that's tracked in [project config](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/project-config.html), in an environment where the [`allowAdminChanges` config setting](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/config/general.html#allowadminchanges) is set to `false`.

To fix the error, make sure that this setting is set to `true` in the `config/general.php` file. When you've completed the upgrade, the setting should be set to `false` in all environments except local/dev.

Comment: Thanks Mats! I knew about `allowAdminChanges` and was 99% sure that I had it set to true. Turns out that I defined it as a conditional env variable (`$isDev = App::env('ENVIRONMENT') === 'dev';`). This normally works perfectly fine, but it seems like the update really didn't like the condition. When setting `allowAdminChanges` to a fixed value of `true` the update ran perfectly. Thanks!